# Error Mosquitto with websockets enabled on FreeBSD

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

Have been trying to install mosquitto with websockets enabled on FreeBSD.

Following are the steps.FreeBSD 10.2-BETA1-p1 , amd64.

1. Installed the available mosquitto port on freebsd.
2. Made changes to the config.mk in File mosquitto-1.4.4.tar.gz located at /usr/ports/distfiles
3. Changed the SHA 256 and the file size in distinfo at /usr/ports/net/mosquitto . This is to make sure the file is not downloaded again from net.
4. pkg remove mosquitto
5. make clean
6. make install
7. Made changes to /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf . [port 1883 listener 9001 protocol websockets]
8. mosquitto -d -c /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

Error: Websockets support not available.

Error found at /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:152.

Unable to figure out what the issue maybe. I checked the work folder in the mosquitto port to see if websockets was set to yes. Everything seems to be correct.

Appreciate your help ,Thanking you all in advance .

GS

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the conf file before you make it. And run make after make clean.